# Pyodbc execution failed on temp table

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I have a Python Script which uses the pyodbc library to run some queries which I have task scheduler running on a set schedule. The script had been working fine without issue all of last week and it suddenly encountered the error:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select * from #output  ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#output'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

This error arises when I try to extract that data from the query using `pd.read_sql`. The very odd part is that no modifications were made to the script at all. It had been working just fine up until today.

I researched similar problems on stackoverflow and attempted using the same solutions (creating a global temp table instead of a local one) and the issue persists. Strangely, the query includes two temp tables, `#data` and `#output` and I'm able to access to contents of `#data` using `pd.read_sql` with no problem, but for whatever reason, attempting to use the same method on the other temp table results in the error above.

The code itself might be a bit long to include on here, but this is what it resembles for the most part (I'll be happy to share the entire thing if it's not an issue):

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()

query = """create table #data (...)

         ... #some other commands here in the middle

         create table #output (...)

         ... #two more lines of SQL commands and that's it
         """

cursor.execute(query)
totals = pd.read_sql("""select * from #output"""), connection)
```

The line `cursor.execute(query)` doesn't appear to generate an error as I get `<pyodbc.Cursor at 0xef2eea0>` if I run up to that line only.

I appreciate the assistance.

EDIT: I suspect the error message is due to the fact that there is a while loop portion before the `create table #output` statement and it is somehow preventing the next commands from executing properly. I've included a bit more detail using my example code from above:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()

query = """create table #data (...)

           ... #some other commands here in the middle

           declare @order int, @limit int, @check varchar(20)
           set @order = 1
           set @limit = (select count(*) from #data where [weekday] = 'Friday')

           while @order <= @limit
           begin

           update #data
           set [order] = @order
           where #data.[date] = (select top 1 [date] from #data where [order] is null order by [date] asc)

           if (select top 1 [weekday] from #data where [order] is not null order by [date] desc) = 'Friday'
                 set @order = @order + 1

           update #data
           set weekly_desc = (select top 1 weekly_desc from #data where [weekday] = 'Friday' and [order] is null order by [date] asc)
           where [order] = @order

           end

           create table #output (...)
              """

cursor.execute(query)
totals = pd.read_sql("""select * from #output""", connection)
```

Comment: From the error message It looks like the name of the table #output is not being passed correctly, try printing the name and check.

Comment: @Fact So I believe the issue stems from what comes before `create table #output` which is a while loop. Somehow I think the while loop is preventing execution of the next line. I've updated the code above with the while loop portion to see if anyone might be able to give me some tips on what the problem might be.

Comment: Double-check your code. Your updated example has mismatched parentheses, specifically `totals = pd.read_sql("""select * from #output"""), connection)` has an extra `)`.

Comment: The error message you posted has also been butchered. Are you sure you didn't just use `pd.read_sql("""select * from ##output""" ...` instead of `pd.read_sql("""select * from #output""" ...`?

Comment: @Gord Thompson Those typos where just in what I had written in the OP, not the code itself. However, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, I found that after updating the `#data` table (the step right before `#create table #output...`, if I had Python execute `pd.read_sql("""select * from #data""", connection)`, the console showed that the final few rows of `#data` contained `NaN` values in the `order` column. I have no idea why it would since running the query in SQL Server executes without issue. This probably explains why it couldn't proceed to the next step which was `create table #output`.

My only way to get it to work again was to rewrite part of the query, specifically the while loop portion, by changing it from

```
while @order <= @limit
begin

update #data
set [order] = @order
where #data.[date] = (select top 1 [date] from #data where [order] is null order by [date] asc)

if (select top 1 [weekday] from #data where [order] is not null order by [date] desc) = 'Friday'
set @order = @order + 1

update #data
set weekly_desc = (select top 1 weekly_desc from #data where [weekday] = 'Friday' and [order] is null order by [date] asc)
where [order] = @order

end
```

to

```
while @order <= @limit
begin

update #data
set [order] = @order
where #data.[date] = (select top 1 [date] from #data where [order] is null order by [date] asc)

if (select top 1 [weekday] from #data where [order] is not null order by [date] desc) = 'Friday'
set @order = @order + 1

end

update #data
set weekly_desc = t.weekly_desc
from (select [order], weekly_desc 
      from #data
      where weekly_desc is not null
      ) as t
where #data.weekly_desc is null
and #data.[order] = t.[order]
```

The `create table #output` step and other commands came after and I was able to have the entire script run without issue. Hoping it doesn't mysteriously stop working again.

Thank you all for your help!